# How to trigger backfill from a task and execute all its downstream tasks sequentially in airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

i am trying to backfill a dag using the airflow backfill command. My requirement is to give a specific task name and start backfill from that task and continue backfilling its downstream tasks.

I tried using task_regex option, but it is running all the mentioned tasks from task-regex in parallel, but those needs to run sequentially in the order mentioned in the dag for me. Can someone please help on how to achieve it.

Here is the sample command i tried using -

```
airflow dags backfill -s 2023-09-18 -e 2023-09-22 --reset-dagruns --donot-pickle -y  --ignore-dependencies --task-regex "^(TaskA|TaskB|TaskC)" "TestDag"
```

Thanks